# How to process Registry section prior the Run section?

Tags: inno-setup

I have noticed that the `[Registry]` section is processed after the `[Run]` section. How can I make the `[Registry]` section to be processed before the `[Run]` section ?

Comment: Why do you want to execute the [Registry] section before [Run] section?

Comment: You can use `[Code]` for `CurStepChanged` with `ssInstall` or  `ssPostInstall`. You can also use `AfterInstall` procedure/function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CurStepChanged` procedure to add Registry Entries at the very beginning of installing files.

As an example:

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then begin
    RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\My Company\My Program',
    'UserName', ExpandConstant('{sysuserinfoname}'));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken.  The `[Registry]` section **is** installed prior to the `[Run]` section.  See the [Installation Order](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_installorder.htm) help topic.